# Cannot Get Zurb Foundation Modal to Close from scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I cannot for the life of me get this zurb foundation modal to close - the only functional 'solution' I have is a hack that throws an error.

check the code comments for what I've already tried - uncommented portion is the hack.

HTML:

```
<div id="indoor-unit-selection" class="product-selection cell small-11 medium-10 large-6 grid-x reveal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="indoor-unit-selection" aria-hidden="true" >
<div data-toggle="indoor-unit-selection" data-close class="grid-x grid-padding-x align-spaced align-middle text-center">
                    <div id="${unit.id}" class="indoor-unit-option cell small-11 medium-10 large-6 grid-x grid-padding-x align-spaced text-center">
                        <div class="indoor-product-description sub-header2 cell small-12">${unit.name}</div>
                        <img class="cell product-image small-5 medium-6" src="${unit.largeImagePath}">
                        <div class="product-information-container cell small-7 medium-6 grid-y grid-padding-y align-spaced text-center">
                            <div class="model-number">Model Number: ${unit.erpNumber}</div>
                            <a class="more-info" href="https://www.behler-young.com${unit.productDetailUrl}" target="_blank">More Information</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr id="hr-${unit.id}"/>
        <a class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>
```

scripts:

```
        console.log('close the modal?');
        // let esc = $.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 27 });
        // $("html").trigger(esc); console.log("ecape keypress simulated");
        // $('#indoor-selection-unit').parent().click();
        $('.close-button').click(); // clickjacking?
        // $('.close-reveal-modal').click(); // clickjacking?
        // $('#indoor-unit-selection').trigger('reveal:close');
        // $('.reveal').trigger('reveal:close');
        // $('#indoor-unit-selection').foundation('reveal', 'close');  // 5th time is a charm?
        // $('#indoor-unit-selection').reveal({dismissModalClass: "close-reveal"});
        // $('.product-election').reveal({ dismissModalClass: "close-reveal" });
        // $('#indoor-unit-selection').trigger('reveal:close')
        // $('#indoor-unit-selection').foundation('reveal', 'close');
        $('#indoor-unit-selection').foundation('close-reveal-modal');
        // $('#indoor-unit-selection').foundation('close');
        // $('#indoor-unit-selection').hide();
```

the data-toggle div --> hr are appended elements from a loop.

expectation - click a unit and the modal closes (along with the other events I have connected to the unit selection - those are working fine)

Answer (score 0):

**Version 6.5.3:**
`$('#my-element').foundation('close');`
https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html#close

**Version 5 Docs:**
`$('#my-element').foundation('reveal', 'close');`
https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/reveal.html

Also, keep in mind, foundation reveal elements shift to the bottom of the page after Foundation initializes, so if you have additional elements for selecting your Reveal modal, that can cause it to break.

Also check for race cases, because foundation initializes at the bottom of the page per their documentation, sometimes scripts are created and authored to be output before the initialization step. Sometimes it makes sense to wrap these inside a `$( window ).on( 'load', function() { /*...*/ } );` event to ensure that all page elements have loaded that need to load.